# I need to show "-" in place of blank cell when there is no data form services and have to show data if it there

Tags: angular

Region of Sale 
                                unfold_more
                            
                             {{element.regionSaleCode}}

Comment: Tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

Use ternary operator like below,

```
{{ element.regionSaleCode ? element.regionSaleCode : '-' }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use directly the or operator where if data then show it or show the blank like below

```
{{ element.regionSaleCode || '-' }}
```